# tkinter GUI freezes when pyttsx3 starts running

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently started learning about pyttsx3 , where you can convert text to speech.
I'm facing a problem where as soon as pyttsx3 starts speaking , my whole GUI freezes until pyttsx3 stops speaking.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3
root = Tk()

def read():
    engine.say(text.get(1.0 , END))
    engine.runAndWait()

engine = pyttsx3.init()

text = Text(width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert(END , "This is a text widget\n"*10)

read_button = Button(root , text = "Read aloud" , command = read)
read_button.pack(pady = 20)

mainloop()
```

Here , when I click on the read aloud button, the entire GUI freezes and I can't do anything with it until pyttsx3 stops speaking.

Is there any way to fix this problem ?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Use thread to execute `read()`.

Comment: Sorry , I don't know how to use thread. Could you please provide an answer so that I can understand ?

Comment: You have to provide some code based on which we can guide you...elz learn threading and implement it

Comment: @coderGtm , I have provided a code in my question.

Comment: @Lenovo 360 Yes i just saw.... donno what was the issue then..maybe coz i hv a very slow connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use thread to execute `read()`:

```py
import threading

...

read_button = Button(root, text="Read aloud", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=read, daemon=True).start())
...
```

Comment: When I implement this , the program keeps running even when I close the window. Any way to avoid this ?

Comment: @Lenovo360 Use `daemon=True` in `Thread(...)`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

use thread u can check my GitHub  demo code for this

https://github.com/rkb9878/KBC/blob/master/kbc_question.py

line no 325

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Also read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).